# Woocommerce Checkout shows that "Billing House No is a Required Field"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

My website is built through wordpress+woocommerce. In the purchase process during the checkout step, although I finished the complete information, I can not properly continue. There will always exist a warning "Billing House No is a Required Field ". But I have checked many times, this field is not in my checkout page form, what is going on?

the url of this checkout page is "https://heromindclub.com/checkout/"

As far as I remember, woocommerce does not have this field

Comment: You have custom code or a checkout field editor plugin that is adding that field, and there is an error during validation. If you have no plugin, look in your child theme's functions.php for the house number custom field

Comment: I do have a plugin related to filed, but I checked the plugin's settings and the "billing house" field did not appear, and the phenomenon persisted even after I deactive the plugin. Then I checked the functions.php of the child theme as you said, and I never modified this file, and I didn't find the reason, is there another way?